# QStandardItemModel within QTtableview

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

I am using QStandardItemModel inside QTtableview. Is it possible to add `checkbox` in on column cell & `combobox` in another column cell.

So that i can select predefined option from the combo box.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first:

You can setFlags() on an QStandardItem to make it checkable:

```
Qt::ItemFlags QStandardItem::flags() const
void QStandardItem::setFlags ( Qt::ItemFlags flags )
Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable
```

( [enum Qt::ItemFlag](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) )

For the second:

You should create your own Custom Delegate class inheriting [QStyledItemDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and reimplement the [createEditor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor), setEditorData and setModelData methods. Check [this link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19414) and, for a more complete example, the [SpinBox Delegate example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html)

Edit: Once you got your custom delegate class, you have to tell your view to use it in a given column with [QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn)